# What is a good approach to pass data through containment view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uistoryboard

[image: Example]

I am trying to pass instance of object from "initial" view controller to "item1" and "item2". I would like to avoid subclassing `UITabBarController` as it would make containment view controller know "too much".

Is there any good approach to do that using storyboards or code besides subclassing `UITabBarController`?

Comment: you can use singleton class, save data in that class and access it in other classes.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar, @aBilal Sorry, by data I meant instance of object. So `NSUserDefaults` and singleton won't not work. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to avoid subclassing UITabBarController as it would make containment view controller know "too much".

You should subclass, and your subclass should implement a specific protocol for this purpose. Yhen, the containing VC only knows about that protocol and it's appropriate because it has that direct responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to pass instance of object from "initial" view controller
>   to "item1" and "item2". I would like to avoid subclassing
>   UITabBarController as it would make containment view controller know
>   "too much".

The problem here is that the `destinationViewController` of your segue is the `UITabBarController` and not *item 1* or *item 2*. This makes your case quite difficult if you don't want to subclass it, because you can't communicate directly between the instances of your *initial VC* and the two items.

My recommendation indeed would be to subclass, that's the right way to go in this situation (you might want to add a protocol that specifies the communication interface).

Other options are:

1. somehow give the initial view controller access to instances of *item 1* and *item 2* (you'll have to do a lot of this setup in code since Storyboards don't give you the power to do it all completely in IB)
2. use `NSNotification` and pass the instances as `userInfo` (not very elegant but might be the quickest solution for your isse)
3. store serialized versions of the instances that you want to pass in `NSUserDefaults` and load them in *item 1* and *item 2* (might be a lot of overhead)